# How to break on invalid cross-thread error

Tags: .net, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, debugging

We just recently upgraded from VS2005 to VS2010. I've noticed that unlike VS2005, when debugging code and the VS2010 IDE encounters an "Invalid Cross Thread" operation, the IDE simply terminates the application without "breaking" on the line of code that is causing the problem.

I looked into the Debug > Exceptions section of the IDE, but I didn't find "Invalid Cross Thread Operation" as a valid option under the System.Threading namespace.  I am kinda lost at how to get the VS2010 IDE to behave like the VS2005 IDE, where it would break code and highlight the line causing an invalid cross-thread operation.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Can you try enabling breaking on ALL exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I turn on all the System.Threading exceptions (even though Cross-Thread is not listed), the IDE now does break on Cross-Thread errors.  I have no clue "which" Threading Exception Namespace holds this particular option, but, now I have my IDE working like VS2005 did.

Answer (score 0):

Change all options on Debug > Exceptions to "Thrown"
That's how the old VS behaved.

Comment: I did as you suggested, turning on all the CLR exceptions to thrown. Problem with that is that every single error, regardless of whether its inside a TRY...CATCH causes teh IDE to break.  This is NOT the behavior of old VS.

Answer (score 0):

Try System.UnauthorizedAccessException.  That catches my cross threading errors

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but for Visual Studio 2017, I will typically get a cross-thread operation exception under System.InvalidOperationException.

The text for the exception is:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'XXXX' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.'
```

I imagine there could be a variety of operations that are considered "cross thread" errors so it could fall under different exception categories.